# Can not add random number with file name using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need one help.I need to add one random number with the file name using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-class="{'myError': billdata.regdoc.$touched && billdata.regdoc.$invalid }">
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="regdoc" id="regdoc"  ng-model="regfile" ngf-pattern="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"  ngf-select="onRegFileSelect($file);" >
</div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.regdoc.$error" ng-if="billdata.regdoc.$touched">
<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field only accepts .pdf,.ppt,.docx files.</p>
</div>
```

My controller file code is given below.

```
var regDocURL='';
$scope.onRegFileSelect=function(files){
        console.log('docs details',files);
        regDocURL=files;
}
var curnum=(Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
var regDocs=regDocURL;
var newRegPath=curnum+"_"+ regDocs.name;
regDocs.name=newRegPath;
console.log('reg file',newRegPath,regDocs);
```

Here in the console message i can not get the new file name which is including some random number.Here i need to include one random number(`i.e-curnum`) with the file name.Please help me.

Comment: what are you using at the backend?

Comment: what do you get in the console message?

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy : I am using PHP for backend.

Comment: and anyway regDocs has your complete file and ng-file-upload module has nothing per say to change names because it used to pass on the file details to the backend.

Comment: You must do that at the backend. I have used ng-file-upload module and at the backend I use nodejs. Try regdocs.name, it is your best option otherwise you'll have to change it at the backend.

Comment: You're using name property of the string?

Comment: Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @FlorianTopf : i am getting output of `newRegPath`  is a new file path name with one random number but same path i can get in `regDocs.name`.Its showing the original path name.

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy : I have already done like this for file type is image but for .pdp/.ppt/.docx..its not happening like that.

Comment: @jcubic :Yes.I am using the name property.

Comment: You mean to say that your code works for other file types but not for images?

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy : it works for only image type but not for other.

Answer (score 0):

here my working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maurosala/vpb0bjoe/)

this is the controller

```
angular.module('app', ["ngFileUpload"]).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.onRegFileSelect=function(files){
      console.log('docs details',files);
      var curnum=(Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
      $scope.newname=curnum+"_"+ files.name;
  }
 });
```

this is HTML

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="file" data-size="lg" ng-model="regfile" ngf-select ngf-change="onRegFileSelect($file);" >
<p>
{{newname}}
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Mauro Sala: what you did.Here i need to replace the new file name(`i.e-newname`) with existing file name(`files`).

Comment: Now what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy : suppose `$scope.newname=1234_abc.pdf` and  before `files.name=abc.pdf`.After adding this random number the `files.name` should be `1234_abc.pdf`.which is not happening.Please check my post again.

Comment: @subhra Please check the fiddle made by Mauro Sala, I believe his solution is what you need and if not I think you should explain your query more clearly.

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy :No,That was not my problem.any way i solved this using `Upload.rename(regDocs, newRegPath);` and it gave me the solution.

Comment: @MauroSala : check your second console message in your second fiddle code the problem is still there.

Comment: Great. Add your solution -> Answer. @subhra

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Upload.rename(file, newName)`. This will upload the file with the new name.

For the purpose of showing the file's new name on the ui you can use the scope variable that you keep the new name in it or you can access it with `file.ngfName`.